# LaTeX breaking up too many words

Tags: latex

I've written a document in LaTeX, using two-column format, 11pt, times font. Many of my words appear hyphenated, and for every description list item, I get a badbox warning (no problems visible in the output though). How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please post a small sample?  Maybe a single page with your content stripped down so that the effect occurs and can be debugged, but not the whole document?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you should set a hyphenation penalty somewhere in your preamble:

```
\hyphenpenalty=750
```

The value of 750 suited my needs for a two column layout on letter paper (8.5x11 in) with a 12 pt font. Adjust the value to suit your needs. The higher the number, the less hyphenation will occur. You may also want to have a look at the `hyphenat`package, it provides a bit more than just hyphenation penalty.

Answer (score 22):

While, yes, you could make TeX less picky or even go the ragged option, this is best fixed by the `microtype` package. Just loading it should do the trick:

```
\usepackage{microtype}
```

It provides two features to improve the typesetting of paragraphs:

- **Margin kerning:** characters, especially punctuation, will protrude a small fraction into the margin. Practically, this has the effect of very slightly increasing the line length and (IMO) visually looks very nice.
- **Font expansion:** as well as stretching/shrinking the space between words to create a flush paragraph, the characters themselves are stretched/shrunk by very small amounts (less than one percent). This is visually imperceptible at the character level but, surprisingly, makes a huge difference at the paragraph level.

Comment: Things moved around a little bit, but there is still a lot of hyphenation. I think I may have to tweak some parameters.

Comment: This sounds awesome. Definitely going to try it out.

Answer (score 4):

I've always just used `\raggedright` for this, but I've never done that for an entire paper.  [This FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=ragright) (which is one of my go-to LaTeX resources) recommends the `ragged2e` package.

Oh, and a side note: I never pay attention to bad boxes unless I can see them in the output.  This is probably dumb, but LaTeX is much pickier than I am.

Comment: Using the draft option — \documentclass[draft]{...} — or using something like \overfullrule=5pt will show overfull boxes in red, so you can notice them and decide if you care. And to make TeX less picky, you can change \hfuzz (e.g. with \hfuzz=1pt).

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you - I can't believe I've never heard of that before.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [the answers from another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31301/how-to-reduce-the-number-of-hyphenation/), I found these settings to be perfect to prevent hyphenation altogether without being ugly:

```
\tolerance=9999
\emergencystretch=10pt
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\exhyphenpenalty=100
```

`\tolerance=9999` allows as much whitespace as possible.

`\emerencystretch=10pt` allows some extra whitespace per line.

`\hyphenpenalty=10000` disables hyphens completly.

`\exhyphenpenalty=100` allows using hyphens which were already present.

Comment: That was so helpful, thank you!